# Qthread calls run only once

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

Hi I am trying to create thread in console application on Qt.

My main method is :

```
#include<featurematcher.h>
#include<QCoreApplication>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

        FeatureMatcher * fm = new FeatureMatcher();

        fm->start();

    return a.exec();

}
```

My FeatureMatches class is as follows :

```
    #ifndef FEATUREMATCHER_H
#define FEATUREMATCHER_H
#include<QThread>

class FeatureMatcher:public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FeatureMatcher();
    void run();
};

#endif // FEATUREMATCHER_H
```

and cpp file :

```
#include "featurematcher.h"
#include <iostream>
FeatureMatcher::FeatureMatcher()
{
}


void FeatureMatcher::run()
{
    std::cout<<"Process"<<std::endl;
}
```

My problem is that when I start running program it only calls run method once.I was expecting output to be infinite number of "process" printed out but it is only printed once.
Where I am missing ?

Comment: What is the problem what you want to solve with QThread? If you expect run to be called repeatedly, you may not need the thread at all, but a QTimer instead.

Comment: A thread is meant to run `run` only once. If you want to execute a task mutliple times you will need a loop.

Comment: @Alexander thank you . I was using thread on GUIs .In that,it was calling run itself but later I learned that it is because GUI is repainting itself and calling thread again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's generally [not a good idea to inherit `QThread`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details). But, if you absolutely have to do it, you'll have to implement loop yourself. You can do it in two ways.

You can create a `QTimer` and then run `QThread::exec`:

```
void FeatureMatcher::run()
{
    this->moveToThread(this);

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(onTimer()));
    timer->setInterval(1000);
    timer->start();
    exec();
}
```

or you can create an infinite loop:

```
void FeatureMatcher::run()
{
    while (1) {
        std::cout<<"Process"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Updated first example #2.**

Comment: Your first example is incorrect. The `onTimer` slot won't be executed in the `FeatureMatcher` thread context.

Comment: @hank: Thanks, haven't used it for a long time. Updated example.

Comment: I was about to try using while loop in run. But I have used thread in a gui application where I don't need to use any loops.Once I started the thread its run function is called every time by itself. Is there any difference of threads on console and gui applications ?

Comment: @Amartel: That is incorrect too. The timer is already created in the `FeatureMatcher` thread context, so there's no need for `timer->moveToThread(this)`. The problem here is that the `FeatureMatcher` object itself is created within the main thread and its `onTimer` will also be executed in the main thread context. To 'fix' this, you should use a hack in the `FeatureMatcher` constructor: `this->moveToThread(this)`, but this is considered a really bad practice.

Comment: @Muhammet Ali Asan: there are no differences. `Once I started the thread its run function is called every time by itself` - this sounds wierd. @hank: Thanks again. Edited.

Comment: Since you are linking against Qt5 doc it would be nice to use the new signal/slot connect format without SIGNAL and SLOT macros.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with what Amartel has said above ("not a good idea to inherit QThread").  It is still an option.

If you still want to inherit QThread (which you really, probably don't need to) try this:

```
    #ifndef FEATUREMATCHER_H
#define FEATUREMATCHER_H
#include<QThread>

class FeatureMatcher:public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FeatureMatcher();
    void loopRun();
private:
    void run();
};

#endif // FEATUREMATCHER_H
```

Then add the looprun() function into your .cpp file:

```
#include "featurematcher.h"
#include <iostream>
FeatureMatcher::FeatureMatcher()
{
}

void FeatureMatcher::run()
{
    std::cout<<"Process"<<std::endl;
}

void FeatureMatcher::looprun()
{
    while(1){
        start();
    }
}
```

I hope I was able to help you out.  There are very few instances where it is benefitial to inherit QThread.

This is blog post by one of the guys who worked with/helped developed the QThread module which explains some of the confusion:  https://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

However, this post makes some arguments against always using worker threads instead of subclassing QThreads:  http://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html

Comment: run is protected virtual that is called when you do QThread::start(). You shouldn't call run directly. Your implementation is not a thread at all.

Comment: Fixed that issue. Thanks for pointing that out Correa!  It's been a bit of time since I did this kind of QThread implementation.